# Borel-Cantelli question

Tags: probability

If $X_1...X_n$ are i.i.d. and $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ how can Borel-Cantelli lemma helps us to proof a.s. of:

$$\max\{X_{n^2+1},X_{n^2+2},\dots,X_{n^2+2n}\}\ge5 \text{, }\forall n>N$$

Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define $A_n=\{X_{n^2+1}<5,\dots,X_{n^2+2n}<5\}$ so that $\mathsf{P}(A_n)=\Phi(5)^{2n}$ and

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf{P}(A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Phi(5)^{2n}<\infty.
$$

Hence, by the first Borel-Cantelli lemma $\mathsf{P}(\limsup A_n)=0$ and $A_n^c$ occurs eventually a.s.

*Note*: $A_n^c=\max\{X_{n^2+1},\dots,X_{n^2+2n}\}\ge5$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Now I understand why need to use Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: what is your $\Phi$? Is it $\mathbb P(X_i)<5$